# Why we must use same volatile field to establish happens-before relationship using the volatile keyword?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The ['Volatile Rule'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) says that 'A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field',
I DO know that this means if we write to a volatile thread and read another volatile in another thread, then there are NO happens-before relationship between the two actions.

My queustion is why we must use 'same field'?

Comment: Because that's the rule?

Comment: If you write to one `volatile` field and read from another field (`volatile` or not), there's no "happens-before" guarantee.

Comment: What else would it say instead? The point is to limit the threads that have to get the latest changes made visible to those that are actually concerned. The Jvm designers want to avoid having to update every thread’s view across the whole program.

Comment: It's a specification. Particular JVMs on particular hardware configurations could have strong guarantees, but you cannot rely on those as the behaviour can be different on a different or newer version of a JVM, or on another hardware configuration. As to the why - you'd have to ask someone who was on the team who create the JMM specification. It's a committee decision and they could have made a different rule as easily.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidtErwin A similar answer could be made for almost every question on SO: "That's the way it is". In this case, I guess knowing how happens-before is implemented on existing or reasonably possible computer architectures would indicate that happens-before can be implemented for one field more efficiently than a global happens-before, and we may *reasonably speculate* the specification writers wanted to allow those efficient implementations.

Answer (score 1):

That is how it should work isn't? All we want is the data shared between threads should be consistent, so why should we have happens-before relationship between different variables? It makes sense to have happens before relationship on same field because if we don't then it may lead to data race. isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Because what you are asking for is covered by `synchronized`: writing to any field of an object through a synchronized method *happens before* subsequently reading any other field of the same object through a synchronized method.

Comment: `synchronized` works similar to `volatile` in the sense that *happens-before* is only guaranteed between threads locking the same monitor. You're making a faulty distinction.